# Send table format to email in Android app

Tags: java, android, html, html-table, html-email

I am trying to send table format in email using an Android application. I have done following things:

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String tblOutDevices= "<html><body><table><tr><td>NO.</td><td>DEVICE NAME</td><td>USER NAME</td></table></body></html>";

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Demo");
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
                {
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(tblOutDevices,0));
                } else {
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(tblOutDevices));
                }

                sendIntent.setType("text/html");

                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });
```

But, when I check in application I cannot see table format in the body.

I have check many question related to this like: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774094/embed-html-table-tag-in-email-intent-android), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787171/sending-html-email-in-android-using-table-etc-is-there-really-no-relativel?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037925/sending-html-email-with-database-table-in-email-body-in-android), [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154790/android-how-to-format-the-text-as-table-in-email-body-of-email-client?noredirect=1&lq=1) etc... But, those was too old. 2-4 year old questions and said that table format is not support. After 2 year there are many updates but, still didn't support table format? If support what is the solution for that?

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the received activity, you to need set that string in webView or use Html APIs or tagHandler to set on a textview

Comment: @Vinodh in received activity? I am sending it to default activity.